# I like to add title and button to the UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I like to add title and button to the UIPopoverController. With my current code

```
- (IBAction)listOfDocumnetsInSections:(id)sender {

UIViewController *listViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.lsitOfDocument = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 300, [self countRecordsInEntity] * 43) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.lsitOfDocument.dataSource = self;
self.lsitOfDocument.delegate = self;

[listViewController.view addSubview:self.lsitOfDocument];
self.listOfSectionsPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:listViewController];

[self.listOfSectionsPopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, [self countRecordsInEntity] * 43)];
[self.listOfSectionsPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(700, 35, 10, 10)
                                            inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];}
```

It looks like

[image]

But I like to change UI like following

[image]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options:

1. add a UIToolbar to the top of your view
2. create a section header for your UITableView that contains a UIToolbar

The UIToolbar will contain the label and button